# Is it possible to access and extract data from a field in a structure?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, alv

First of all, I want to remember that I am new to the Abap language and I started studying it recently.

My problem is the following: I was creating an ALV view and eventually needed data from a GAMNG field in the CAUFVD structure.
I researched to try to extract data from the GAMNG field and from what I understand structures are like models to facilitate table creation but I'm not sure.

So my question is:

Is it possible to use data that references structures and place it as a new column in the ALV view? And how I do it ?

*(the process I did was go to transaction co03 -> enter the material code -> press f1 on top of total quantity -> and see which field this data was in, which in this case is GAMNG)

Comment: The answer will depend on the exact situation. In your case, it's `co03` so please mention it clearly in the question. Probably the answer won't be valid for anything else.